# Android WebView opening links in default browser - Open links in app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I created an android application with WebView property and everything is fine, but the only problem is that when I click any link within that WebView, it automatically go for default web browser. But I want to open links within my application web view only. Here my code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://plan.regenbogen-gesamtschule.de/vertretung/schueler/subst_001.htm");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` in your `MyAppWebViewClient` and return `false`, your webview should automatically attempt to load the url. The documentation states the following:

> Return: True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

see [shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) documentation.

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){

    @Override
    boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //hide loading image
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //show webview
        findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }});
```

Comment: Actually I'm new to Android can you please explain me what do you mean by it I didn't get it so clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.